# How to find specific value from multiple arrays in php?

Tags: php

How to find specific value from multiple arrays in php?

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 7 [5] => 8 [6] => 22 )
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

this is my code

```
                 <?php if(is_array("22", $parentCategories)) :  ?>


                  <?php  echo "Get"; 

                  else : 

                    echo "Not get";

                  endif; exit();
                  ?>
```

i have these arrays but i only want to find value 22 in filter. i am already using in_array but it only check last array values not others

Comment: *i am already using in_array* - can you add the code you already have to the question as text please.

Comment: Iterate over your arrays and apply `in_array` to each.

Comment: If it’s checking just the last value may indicate that there is some problem in your code. Please share your complete code in the question.

Comment: <?php if(is_array("22", $parentCategories)) :  ?>
                         

                      <?php  echo "Get"; 

                      else : 

                        echo "Not get";

                      endif; exit();
                      ?>

Comment: it just checking last array values .

Comment: You're using `is_array`, not `in_array`.

Comment: You're only testing one array. How are you looping among all the arrays?

Comment: $parentCategories   having this above array

Comment: What variables contain the other 4 arrays? You need to test all of them.

Comment: If there's a loop that sets `$parentCategories` to different arrays, this code needs to be inside the loop. If it's after the loop, the variable just contains the value from the last iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one, assuming that your array_depth is not changing

```
$existing = false;
foreach ($parentCategories as $k => $v) {
    if( in_array('22', $v) ){
        $existing = true;
    }
}
if( $existing ){
    echo "GET";
}else{
    echo "NOT GET";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `array_walk_recursive` method to achieve your goal, it's not the perfect solution but it works.

```
$array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [[5, 6], [7,8]]
];

$search = 8;
$hasValue = false;

// $hasValue must be passed by reference
$result = array_walk_recursive($array, function($current, $index, $search) use (&$hasValue) {
    if ($hasValue) return;

    $hasValue = $current == $search;
}, $search);

if ($hasValue) {
    echo "Get";
} else {
    echo "Not Get";
}
```